# How to get last record in db2 using max function

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get the last record of that table by using max() function.

Query

```
select oafaci, oaorno, min(obfded) ,max(oblded) from mvxcdtpusd.oohead join mvxcdtpusd.ooline on oacono = obcono and oaorno = oborno and oafaci = obfaci and oawhlo = obwhlo where obitno like '19140%' and OBCONO = 888 group by OAFACI, OAORNO
```

Result

```
OAFACI  OAORNO      FDate            LDate
812 0000556215  20130109    20130109
812 0000554203  20130102    20130102
812 0000553769  20121017    20121017
812 0000554204  20130130    20130130
812 0000556214  20121024    20121024
812 0000556216  20130206    20130206
```

From that result table- i want the below data.

Desire Result

```
812 0000556216  20130206    20130206
```

Need help to get the last record by using max()

Comment: what is the result of this?

Comment: If you are storing data as string, I think this is impossible. EDIT: I mean impossible via max() function.

Comment: @ JW - i want the last record line no 7

Comment: @LeonardoRaele oafaci,oaorno are string type . Fdate and Ldate are date.

Comment: How is the above query sorted?

Answer (score 7):

Why do you *need* to use the `max()` function?  If this is homework, you should state that in the question.

The best way to get the last record is something like:

```
select *
from t
order by date
fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 2):

***Try*** this query,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tablename
WHERE   OAFACI = 812 AND
        OAORNO = (SELECT MAX(OAORNO) 
                    FROM tableName
                    WHERE OAFACI = 812)
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  OAFACI, MAX(FDATE) max_date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY OAFACI
        ) b ON  a.OAFACI = b.OAFACI AND
                a.FDATE = b.max_date
-- WHERE    a.OAFACI = 812
```

Comment: the query is based on the greatest `OAORNO`. did you get any errors? do you want to get the latest record for every `OAFACI`?

Comment: yes..actually.. there is no identity for this table... {select oafaci, oaorno, min(obfded) ,max(oblded)  from mvxcdtpusd.oohead join
mvxcdtpusd.ooline on oacono = obcono and oaorno = oborno and oafaci = obfaci and oawhlo = obwhlo
where obitno like '19140%' and OBCONO = 888
group by OAFACI, OAORNO}

Comment: this is sql , i generate for the above table /result. i just want every last record from that table only.

Comment: if that's the case, then why can't you also add sample records along with your question and also the desired result.

Comment: hi JW, it can get the last record. Thanks for help.